# Unknown type name in header file prototype

Tags: c, typedef, header-files, function-prototypes

I have *lexer.c* file, which should be included to another .c file. It have

`int getToken(string *attribute) {}`

function and same prototype in *lexer.h* header file. Also i have helper *str.c* file for simplify work with strings. It has header file with declaration of type **string**:

```
typedef struct {
    char* str;      //string with \0 at the end
    int length;     //length of the string
    int allocated;  //allocated memory size
} string;
```

So, lexer.h included from main file. Then lexer.c starts with:

```
#include "str.h"
#include "lexer.h"
```

As i understanding, after including *str.h* type **string** is visible for *lexer.c* and lexer.h.
But i have compilation error at the prototype in header file:

```
./lexer.h:65:14: error: unknown type name 'string'
int getToken(string *attribute);
             ^
1 error generated.
```

How can i use this type in header file?

Comment: Check for #ifdef's or other reasons your typedef may get excluded... and unrelated to your issue but `I have lexer.c file, which should be included to another .c file.` -- if that's not a type.... don't #include one .c into another. It might work ok sometimes but as a pattern to follow it will eventually cause problems.

Comment: Why don't you make it simple, your custom declarations into one common header file and include it in required .c files.

Comment: @mah sorry for my writing style, i meant included to another .c files via lexer.h header file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not clear now which files include which. Let me try to recapitulate this:

- `lexer.c` includes `str.h` and `lexer.h`
- `main.c` includes `lexer.h`

Is that right? In this case, `main.c` cannot be compiled as, indeed, the definition of the `string` type is missing.

As `lexer.h` *always* requires `str.h` to be included, it might be a good idea to out `#include "str.h"` into this header file.

Comment: yes, thats right! thanks for the help, including str.h to main.c solved my problem. works without #include "str.h" in header file

Comment: @MarkBirger Of course it works. But it might help preventing such things, if all header files are "self-contained", i. e. work without requiring that the includer includes the needed things as well.

Comment: Oh.. i understand, if i'll include all "dependencies" to .h file, i don't need to include str.h to every file.

Comment: Yes. At least, provided that all `.h` files support to be included multiple times, e. g. with a include guard protection, or being simple enough just to contain statements which may be repeated.